# Automatically citing all entries in a class in a bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, resume

I usually add my publications to my CV from my bib file (using biblatex). At first, I used to manually cite each entry, but as the list grows, it's becoming a chore (especially since there are quite a few publications in between my CV updates and I can never seem to remember the chronological order). I would like to be able to tell `biblatex` to scan my bib file, pull out all `@article` entries and cite them under a heading "Journal publications", then all the `@inproceedings` entries and cite them under "Conference proceedings" and so on (i.e., without individually citing them).

I can manage naming/styling the sections and headings, but I'm stuck at doing the automatic citing. How can I do this? Here's a very minimal example without the frills to get started:

#### The .bib file:

```
@article{Doe2012a,
    author  = {J. Doe},
    title   = {Lorem Ipsum -- Part I},
    journal = {J. Dolor Sit Am.},
    volume  = {1},
    pages   = {1--10},
    month   = {1},
    year    = {2012},
}

@article{Doe2012b,
    author  = {J. Doe},
    title   = {Lorem Ipsum -- Part II},
    journal = {J. Dolor Sit Am.},
    volume  = {2},
    pages   = {11--20},
    month   = {2},
    year    = {2012},
}

@book{Doe,
    author    = {J. Doe},
    title     = {Lorem Ipsum -- Complete Works},
    publisher = {{Dolor S. Amet and Sons}},
    year      = {2011},
}
```

#### The .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex,lipsum}
\addbibresource{path/to/bib/file}

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Publications}
%Scan the bib file and print all @article entries in descending order here!

\section{Dolor sit Amet}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you want to use the `type=<entrytype>` option to `\printbibliography` (§ 3.6.2 in the manual).  E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title=Articles, type=article]

\printbibliography[title={Conference Proceedings}, type=inproceedings]

\end{document}
```

Using the supplied bibliography items:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Doe2012a,
    author  = {J. Doe},
    title   = {Lorem Ipsum -- Part I},
    journal = {J. Dolor Sit Am.},
    volume  = {1},
    pages   = {1--10},
    month   = {1},
    year    = {2012},
}

@article{Doe2012b,
    author  = {J. Doe},
    title   = {Lorem Ipsum -- Part II},
    journal = {J. Dolor Sit Am.},
    volume  = {2},
    pages   = {11--20},
    month   = {2},
    year    = {2012},
}

@book{Doe,
    author    = {J. Doe},
    title     = {Lorem Ipsum -- Complete Works},
    publisher = {{Dolor S. Amet and Sons}},
    year      = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=nty, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Articles, type=article]
\printbibliography[title={Conference Proceedings}, type=inproceedings]
\printbibliography[title={Books}, type=book]
\end{document}
```

I get the two articles under 'Articles' and the one book under 'Books', while the nothing is printed under 'Conference Proceedings' (including even the section title).

Comment: Ooh, that does looks like what I need! Thanks. However, I seem to be getting only one bib item displayed in the output (although I agree that this should work in principle). Do you have any ideas of what could've happened?

Comment: @user24497 -- If I try using your supplied bib entries (and add a line for `type=book`), I get the two entries under 'Articles', nothing under 'Conference Proceedings', and one entry under 'Books'.  Are you using the same bib items?

Comment: If I run your self-contained `.tex` file using my MWE, I get `LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 38.` (and for lines 39 and 40), which correspond to the three `\printbibliography` statements and no `PDF` file is output.

Comment: @user24497 -- Yes, but then run `biber` and `latex` again. (Or use `bibtex`, but then fix the options to `biblatex`....)

Comment: d'oh! I forgot to set my vim-latex compiler to `biber`! Thanks! It works perfectly now :)

Comment: @user24497 -- haha.  I do that sort of thing all the time.  ... Well, I should probably say, I *would* do that sort of thing all the time -- if not for `emacs` ;)

Comment: Haha, there was a time when I would've taken the bait, but these days, I go after the cavemen that still use notepad/gedit =)