# biblatex: List of publications in the CV

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cv

I am writing my CV using the `article` class. How can I list my journal publications and conference presentations each in a separate section? I saved my publication in the `.bib` database.

Comment: Does this [Automatically citing all entries in a class in a bib file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94158/15717) work ?

Comment: have a look at the `bibunits` package; if you split your `.bib` file into separate parts for journals and conference papers, you can use the `\nocite{*}` command for each.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43522) to [Citing a certain type of reference using biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43476)

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that the tag you have set is correct (you are using `biblatex`) you should not use `multibib` or other packages, which are not compatible. It can all be done within `biblatex`. The basic method is as follows:

Instead of a simple `\printbibliography` command, you enter `\printbibliography[]` The optional command (which I have shown with `[]`) limits that bibliography to a particular sub-category of materials: here you put one of the filtering commands described below.

Of course, you then have to tell the package what category to use. For that you use one of the following instructions.

- `type=` will include only works of a certain entry type, e.g. `type=book` will include only books. You can only have **one** `type` instruction: `type=book, type=article` will **not** work. (This is common to all the examples that follow: you can have only one **inclusive** instruction, but more than one **exclusion**. If you want complex tests, you need to set up a custom `bibfilter`.
- `nottype=` will exclude all works in the given type, e.g. `nottype=book` will exclude all books. You can have more than one `nottype` instruction. `nottype=book, nottype=article` will **exclude** both books and articles.
- `keyword=` will include works based on whether a keyword (which can be anything) has been set in your `.bib` file. For instance, in your `.bib` file you could put `keywords = {important}` by things you thought were especially important; then you could print a bibliography of just the "important" works with `\printbibliography[keyword=important]`.
- `notkeyword=` will **exclude** works based on whether a keyword (which can be anything) has been set in your `.bib` file.
- `category=` will include works based on whether you have assigned the work to a category in your `.tex` file. To do that you first set up a category with `\DeclareBibliographyCategory{}` in your preamble, and then assign works (by their key) using `\addtocategory{category}{key}` in the document. Basically this serves a similar function to keywords, but it lets you set them in your `.tex` source rather than your `.bib` file, so they can be document specific.
- `notcategory=` will exclude works based on whether you have assigned them to a category.
- Finally, if you have complex needs you can set up a custom filter, using `\defbibfilter` which lets you combine various tests using *and*, *or* and *not*, which are covered extensively in the `biblatex` documentation (3.6.7).

You may also want to adjust the titles used. Usually, you want something like:

```
\printbibheading% <- Prints "References"

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,
                   title={Articles},
                   type=article]
```

The `title` option controls what is printed. The `heading` option controls the formatting (in this case to print as a sub-heading, in effect).

So, in your case, you will want to work out how to identify articles and conference papers. You may be able to map those simply to entrytypes, such as `article` and `inproceedings`, or you may need to use keywords (if, for instance, some of your conference papers have the `article` type in your `.bib` file). Then simply use `\nocite{*}` to make all the references available for typesetting and then produce two (or more) filtered bibliographies using one of the filters above.

The alternative way of dividing bibliographies uses `refsections` and `refsegments`. It is rather intended for cases where you want to produce bibliographies for different parts of a document (e.g. for each chapter separately), than for bibliographies that are divided by topic.

Comment: @ Paul Stanley can you give me some helps at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297365/how-to-use-bibtex-for-putting-a-nice-publication-list-in-resume-with-document-cl

Comment: For a CV, how can I filter for my own name to have a list of my publications?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `refsection` environment in `biblatex` to divide your reference list into several section.
For a CV I'd suggest something like:

```
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{key1}
\printbibliography[heading=Publications]
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
\nocite{key2}
\printbibliography[heading=Conference presentations]
\end{refsection}
```

And so on

Comment: @ Roey Angel can you give me a guidance here at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297365/how-to-use-bibtex-for-putting-a-nice-publication-list-in-resume-with-document-cl