# options for styling \fullcite

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a list of biblatex items in a document which additionally has a bibliography section. In this part I want to list some bibliography items with `\fullcite` but in a different style then the main bibliography.

I can change the number of authors like this:

```
\begingroup
\defcounter{minnames}{2}
\fullcite{key}
\endgroup
```

How can I further modify the style of `\fullcite`?

MWEB

```
\documentclass[en-US,de-DE]{article}

\usepackage[
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  maxnames=2,
  backend=biber,
  safeinputenc,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
  maxcitenames=2,
  urldate=iso8601,
  date=iso8601
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  pagetotal = {383},
  edition = {1},
  pages = {151--154},
  url = {http://www.google.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
text1

\fullcite{key}

text2

\cite{key}

text3

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

I want to remove the year, URLs from these items listed by `\fullcite` as well and any page numbers and the edition of books?

[image: pdf rendering]

Comment: know there are "better" ways to make a publications list like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115143/biblatex-list-of-publications-in-the-cv but thats not what I need.

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead post a minimal document that shows what you're doing and some sample `.bib` items. And you haven't specified enough information: page numbers from all entry types? Editions from all entry types? etc.

Comment: I second Alan's request. You probably could do this with the combined use of the `\AtNextCitekey` hook and `\clearfield`. But, in this case, it is hard to help without a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: added mweb. in my original document I have 12 items to list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this: you can redefine the `\fullcite` command to clear the fields you don't want, or as noted in the comments, you can use `\AtEverycitekey` to do the same thing.

Conceptually, modifying `\fullcite` seems like the better solution, since using `\AtEveryCitekey` modifies any citation, so if you want to remove any information from the `\fullcite` that is normally included in the regular `\cite` then you *must* use this solution.

If you're just removing URL, edition and pages from the `\fullcite` there will be no bad side-effects of using `\AtEveryCitekey` since it is only the `\fullcite` citation command that would ever output those fields.  But if you want to remove the year as well (as you mention in the comments), then modifying `\fullcite` is the only way to do it.  I've removed the `\AtEveryCitekey` solution from the code for this reason, but placed it separately at the end.

Depending on the type of information you need to suppress, you may need to use one of `\clearfield`, `\clearlist` or `\clearname`.  In the case of `publisher`, or `location`, for example, their type is a list, and so you need to use `\clearlist` to clear them.  Section 2.2.2 of the `biblatex` documentation describes each field and its data type.

```
\documentclass[en-US,de-DE]{article}

\usepackage[
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  maxnames=2,
  backend=biber,
  safeinputenc,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
  maxcitenames=2,
  urldate=iso8601,
  date=iso8601
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  pagetotal = {383},
  edition = {1},
  pages = {151--154},
  url = {http://www.google.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\clearfield{url}%
   \clearfield{pages}%
   \clearfield{pagetotal}%
   \clearfield{edition}%
   \clearfield{labelyear}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\begin{document}
text1
\cite{key}

\fullcite{key}

text2

\cite{key}

text3

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Using `\AtEveryCitekey`

As noted above, using `\AtEveryCitekey` can also work if there is no overlap in the information you need in a regular cite and the information you suppress in the `\fullcite`.  Here's the code to use that method:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{
\clearfield{url}
   \clearfield{pages}
   \clearfield{pagetotal}
   \clearfield{edition}
   \clearfield{labelyear}
}
```

Comment: It would also be safe to just clear these fields in the `\AtEveryCitekey` hook. That way one doesn't need to redefine `\fullcite`.

Comment: @moewe in my preliminary tests I tried that with `\AtNextCite` but it didn't work, but I didn't try `\AtNextCitekey`. Should they have different behaviour?

Comment: Yes indeed. `\AtEveryCite` is executed at the beginning of a cite command, at that point the entry data is not yet available. `\AtEveryCitekey` is executed for every cite entry separately and at a point where the data is available. For `\cite{sigfridsson,worman}` `\AtEveryCite` is executed once at the beginning and `\AtEveryCitekey` once for `sigfridsson` and once for `worman`. The two are conceptually similar to `\AtBeginBibliography` and `\AtEveryBibitem`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks. I'll update the answer to show that option too.

Comment: There seems to be extra whitespace added between text1 and A. Author

Comment: @MaxN Damn end of line spaces! :) Add `%` after each `\clearfield` in the redefinition of `\fullcite` or use the `\AtEveryCitekey` version.  I've edited the code.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the **(2001)** ?
Where can I find documentation on this whole thing, and how do you know those? I looked in the biblatex manual and I don't see the info there.

Comment: @MaxN I've updated the solution. If you want to remove the year, then you can't use the `\AtEveryCitekey` solution. I've explained how this works. As for finding out about this stuff, much of it *is* in the `biblatex` manual, but to understand more of the internals, you also need to browse the actual code of the package. (It would be nice to have a map...).

Comment: Oh, no.. There is one more thing: It's kind of silly to have my own name in my list of publications, however, I need the co-authors to be there for papers with co-authors. Sorry, so complicated.

Comment: @MaxN If you are in a field that remotely uses some sort of author ordering to attribute responsibility to a paper, then removing your name is *not* a good idea.  But I think that should be for a separate question, linking to this one. But search around, since there are likely various similar questions about highlighting or removing particular authors on the site.

Comment: @AlanMunn I think I'll have to make one, because I don't find any.

Comment: strangely `\clearfield{publisher}%` doesn't remove the publisher.

Comment: @MaxN I've added some explanation why. `publisher` is a list, not a simple field.

Comment: @maxN I have in mind [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304968/2693) although how to get it to work just for `\fullcite` is not clear to me.

Comment: Can I not construct it by adding fields rather then removing them? Alternatively how do I remove all fields (so that I can comment out some of these removals to ensure only these  commented out fields are shown).

Comment: @Kvothe I'm not sure I understand your question. But if you want you ask a new question linking to this one.