# Segmenting bibliography based on \addbibresource file

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I have a variation of the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94158/automatically-citing-all-entries-in-a-class-in-a-bib-file) which is about printing all citations from a `.bib` file sourced with `\addbibresource{/path/to/file.bib}`.

While there is much info around on segmenting the bibliograpy by type (e.g. article vs book), I would like to segment the bibliography by which .bib file holds the reference. I maintain .bib files for different topics and would like to issue full bibliographies for each of those collections.

I was thinking there might be an option for `\printbibliography{}` to segment by source (each `\addbibresource{}` file), but perhaps there is a 'better' way?

Minimal working example, with one list from one file only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    %bibencoding=utf8,
    refsegment=section,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    style=numeric
]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title=References in collection X] %, type=article]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use the `category`-related stuff (`\addtocategory`, etc.), then have traditional bibliographical subdivisions.  Or do it by `keywords`: give all entries in a `.bib` file the same, unique-to-that-file keyword, and then print bibliographies that way.