# At the output the bibliography isn't displayed. Why?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I want to add the bibliography at the end of this article so I wrote the following code:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newtheorem{mylemma}{Λήμμα} 
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Θεώρημα}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Ορισμός}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Παράδειγμα} 


\begin{document} 

\title{ }

\author{ M } 

\date{ }


\maketitle 

\clearpage 

\tableofcontents 

....

\clearpage 

....

\nocite{*}  

\medskip

\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{mybibliography} 


\end{document}
```

At the file `mybibliography.bib` I added the following:

```
    @article{
  author =       "\foreignlanguage{english}{TP}",
  title =        "{\foreignlanguage{english}{Extensions}}",
  journal =      "\foreignlanguage{english}{The Journal}",
  volume =       "18",
  number =       "2",
  pages =        "372-397",
  year =         "1994",
  DOI =          "..."
}
```

At the output the bibliography isn't displayed. Why? Have I done something wrong?

**EDIT:**

Having added the command `\nocite{*}` the output is the following:

[image]

Just the numbers are appeared but not the name of the article... What else could I change?

Comment: Did you perform the normal cycle: (pdf)latex -> bibtex (or biber) -> pdf)latex -> pdf)latex? Did you make citations in your text? If not, add `\nocite{*}` before calling the bibliography.

Comment: Possible duplicate (actually independent of using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)): [Automatically citing all entries in a class in a `.bib` file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94158/5764)

Comment: I added the command '\nocite{*}' and I added the output in my initial post. Could you take a look at it? @Bernard

Comment: After adding `\nocite{*}` did you run the cycle again? That is `(pdf)latex -> bibtex -> (pdf)latex -> (pdf)latex`? Although the output looks odd, even if you didn't. Do you get any errors or warnings when you run BibTeX?

Comment: How do we run this cycle? I use sharelatex... I don't get any errors... @cfr

Comment: The thing is, there is nothing wrong with the code you've posted. Here's [what I get](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xJEQg.png) when I run that sequence. I don't use sharelatex myself. On overleaf, the relevant commands are run automatically but I think sharelatex does not do that for you.

Comment: Have you [read this](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex)? Scroll down for the BibTeX section of the page.

Comment: HAve you compiled more than one time? Best would be three times? (If sharelatex includes a bibliography call with bibtex it should run errorless, but that is a guess I do not use sharelatex) With MiKTeX I have no errors with your given code ...  Have you considered to install a tex distribution on your computer?

Comment: @cfr Yes, I think ShareLaTeX also runs all that's needed. Mary: Your code works fine when  I test it on ShareLaTeX: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/521ccc3fe1f4b692043d197d

Comment: I edited at my initial post the content of mybibliography.bib since the name of the article is in english and since I have used the usepackage \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}. Could you take a look at it? Now it doesn't work when we use the command \foreignlanguage{english}, right? How can we write something in english there? @TorbjørnT.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem (see the ShareLaTeX link in my previous comment), but I don't know how to fix that, sorry. (By the way, your example can be reduced quite a bit, see again my test on ShareLaTeX.)

Comment: your bib file looks wrong, there should be a key such as `@article{tp,....`

Comment: As David wrote in his comment your example bib-entry is missing the bib-key. But if you were really using such a faulty bib-entry your document wouldn't imho compile at all on sharelatex. So try to make a *real* example which really shows your error. Create on sharelatex a new small test-document and new test.bib with some entries that you then can test and show us fully.

Comment: I added a key such as '@article{tp,.... ' and now it works!! Thank you!! :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - you should make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bib file looks wrong, there should be a key such as

```
@article{tp,
  ....
```