# Multiple bibliographies with the same counter

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

Following [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24501/biblatex-enumerating-sorted-bibliography-using-authoryear-ibid-style) to number the entries in the bibliography and [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94158/automatically-citing-all-entries-in-a-class-in-a-bib-file) to have multiple bibliographies, I am able to show two bibliographies with separate counters.

I want to have the same counter for both bibliographies. For that, I thought I can use `enumitem` like in the MWE below. However, this does not work for some reason. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to have a single counter for both bibliographies using `enumitem` or otherwise?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Doe2012a,
    author  = {J. Doe},
    title   = {Lorem Ipsum -- Part I},
    journal = {J. Dolor Sit Am.},
    volume  = {1},
    pages   = {1--10},
    month   = {1},
    year    = {2012},
}

@article{Doe2012b,
    author  = {J. Doe},
    title   = {Lorem Ipsum -- Part II},
    journal = {J. Dolor Sit Am.},
    volume  = {2},
    pages   = {11--20},
    month   = {2},
    year    = {2012},
}

@book{Doe,
    author    = {J. Doe},
    title     = {Lorem Ipsum -- Complete Works},
    publisher = {{Dolor S. Amet and Sons}},
    year      = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=nty, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\begin{enumerate}[resume]
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\end{enumerate}}
  {\item}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Articles, type=article]
\printbibliography[title={Books}, type=book]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `[series=bib, resume=bib]` rather than just `resume`, which seems to work. I'm not going to post that as an answer because I don't understand `enumitem` well enough to be sure it's actually correct or why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with a simple `[resume]` here is that biblatex bibliography printing introduces additional grouping, so we don't execute something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item Lorem
  \item ipsum
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item dolor
  \item sit
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

we actually execute

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item Lorem
  \item ipsum
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item dolor
  \item sit
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

But the `[resume]` feature is local, so the numbering just restarts.

One way to work around this has been mentioned by [Paul Stanley](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5404/paul-stanley) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541823/multiple-bibliographies-with-the-same-counter#comment1368575_541823): use a named `resume` key.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=nty, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\begin{enumerate}[resume=bib]}
  {\end{enumerate}}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,cicero,yoon,aksin}
\printbibliography[title=Articles, type=article]
\printbibliography[title={Books}, type=book]
\end{document}
```

[image: Two consecutively numbered bibliographies.]